# Java: 1 key with multiple values using data structure

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashset, multimap

I have a list of objects having code and user name. I can get the code and username with `getCode()` and `getUserName()`. I can think of using MultiMap if I must display only code and list of usernames associated for each code. But how to display all three details (code, usercount, usernames) with different data types using Java?

Code - String (Key)

UserCount - Integer (Value)

UserNames - List (Value)

How to display in the below format using Java?

Code        UserCount      UserNames

Abc         2              Jack, Mary

Def         1              Steven

Ghi         3              James, Ray, Jim

Comment: why not a Map<String, ArrayList<YourObjects>> ? You can then iterate with code and print how many element the array has. (key for the map is your code)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you have a `List<YourObject>` where `YourObject` is the class :

```java
public class YourObject {
    public String code;
    public String userName;
    
    // getters and constructor(s)
}
```

When you say :

> I must display only code and list of usernames associated for each code

It means that in your `List<YourObject>`, if two objects A and B have the same code value X, you want to display something like "Code X ; usernames = [A.getUserName(), B.getUserName()]" ?

But you also want to add a `userCount` attribute which is the size of the usernames list (in my above exemple : 2).

I think you can create a utility method that takes your `List<YourObject>` as parameter and return a `Map<String,List<String>>` where the key string is the code and the List of strings is the usernames.

Something like : (Sorry for the stream version, I was too lazy to write more lines) :

```java
public static Map<String,List<String>> process(List<YourObject>  list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(YourObject::getCode, x -> list.stream().filter(e -> x.getCode().equals(e.getCode())).map(YourObject::getUserName).collect(Collectors.toList()), (x,y) -> x));
}
```

The display you wanted :

```java
process(yourList).forEach((k,v) -> {
    System.out.println("Code : " + k + " | userCount :" + v.size() + " | Usernames =" + v)
});
```